How is the Yang-Baxter equation equivalent to the Braid equation?
Note: The origins of the Yang-Baxter equation is in physics, not mathematics.
Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $R: V \otimes V \to V \otimes V$ be a linear operator. Consider a labelled (for notational convenience) vector space $V_1 \otimes V_2 \otimes V_3$ where $V_1 = V_2 = V_3$. Let $R_{ij} := R: V_i \otimes V_j \to V_i \otimes V_j$. The Yang-Baxter equation is
$$R_{12}R_{13}R_{23} = R_{23}R_{13}R_{12}. \tag{*}$$
In what sense is the Yang-Baxter equation equivalent to the Braid equation
$$\tilde{R}_{12}\tilde{R}_{23}\tilde{R}_{12} = \tilde{R}_{23}\tilde{R}_{12}\tilde{R}_{23}.$$

The two equations are equivalent in the following sense.
Equivalence: Let $P: V \otimes V \to V \otimes V$ be defined by $P(x \otimes x') = x' \otimes x$. Then, $R$ solves the Yang-Baxter equation if and only if $PR$ solves the Braid equation.
Proof: Let $R: V\otimes V \to V \otimes V$ be a linear operator that satisfies the Yang-Baxter equation. Define $\tilde{R} := PR$. Then,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\tilde{R}_{12} \tilde{R}_{23} \tilde{R}_{12} &\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} P_{12}R_{12}P_{23}R_{23}P_{12}R_{12} \\ 
&= R_{21}P_{13}R_{13}R_{12} \text{ (since $P_{12} X_{12} P_{12} = P_{12} X_{12} P_{12}^{-1} = X_{21}$)} \\ 
&= P_{13}R_{23}R_{13}R_{12} \\
&\stackrel{YB}{=} P_{13}R_{12}R_{13}R_{23} \\
&= R_{32}R_{31}R_{21}P_{13} \\
&=P_{23}R_{23}P_{23}R_{31}R_{21}P_{13} \\
&= \tilde{R}_{23}P_{23}R_{31}R_{21}P_{13} \\
&= \tilde{R}_{23}R_{21}P_{23}R_{21}P_{13} \\
&= \tilde{R}_{23}R_{21}P_{23}P_{13}R_{23} \\
&= \tilde{R}_{23}\tilde{R}_{12}P_{12}P_{23}P_{13}R_{23} \\
&= \tilde{R}_{23}\tilde{R}_{12}P_{23}R_{23} \text{ (since $P_{12}P_{23}P_{13} = P_{23}$)}\\
&= \tilde{R}_{23}\tilde{R}_{12}\tilde{R}_{23}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where "def" denotes that a definition was used to produce the equality and "YB" denotes that the Yang-Baxter equation was used to produce the equality.

In some communities, the term Yang-Baxter equation is indeed used to mean the braid equation, either up to a permutation (as in the answer of the OP) or sometimes even for the exact same equation.
In the field of integrability, however, we often prefer to reserve the term Yang-Baxter equation for the generalisation of the equation $(*)$ in the OP where the R-matrix depends on a spectral parameter:
$$R_{12}(u,v) \, R_{13}(u,w) \, R_{23}(v,w) = R_{23}(v,w) \, R_{13}(u,w) \, R_{12}(u,v) \, .$$
Here each vector space (e.g. site with a spin), labelled by a subscript, carries its own spectral parameter: $u$ for the first space, etc. (In many examples, the R-matrix obeys the 'difference property' $R(u,v) = R(u-v)$.)
The argument from the answer of the OP shows that the operator $\check{R}(u,v) \equiv P \, R(u,v)$ then satisfies Yang--Baxter equation in the 'braid-like form'
$$\check{R}_{12}(u,v) \, \check{R}_{23}(u,w) \, \check{R}_{12}(v,w) = \check{R}_{23}(v,w) \, \check{R}_{12}(u,w) \, \check{R}_{23}(u,v) \, , $$
where the subscripts are always adjacent.
The special case where $\check{R}(u,v)$ is independent of $u,v$ is the braid equation.
The conceptual difference is that, just as one can think of $\check{R}$ (with or without spectral parameter) as a deformation, or at least variant, of the permutation $P$, one can think of $R = P\,\check{R}$ as a deformation, or at least variant, of the identity. More precisely, if the R-matrix has the property $R(u,v) = \mathbf{1} + O(\hbar)$, where $\hbar$ is the deformation parameter (usually is not actually Planck's constant), then $R(u,v) = \mathbf{1} + \hbar \, r(u,v) + O(\hbar^2)$. Here the semiclassical limit $r$ of $R$ is the classical r-matrix (with or without spectral parameter), see e.g.
This MathOverflow answer for a little more.

NB. At least in integrability, the notation $\check{R}$ is more common than $\tilde{R}$, and $\check{R}(u,v)$ is pronounced as the 'R-check matrix'.
